# Do dead Adventurer's count?

Tags: betrayal-at-baldurs-gate

In playing a round of Betrayal at Baldur's Gate we ran into an interesting situation. We got haunt 44, and in the first round before the traitor is revealed one of the players killed another. Three of us were gathered on the Gladiator's Pit, wanting to pick up a point of Might before the traitor was found. The Wizard had found the fake amulet and the Cleric had failed to pick up his. So the Warlock looked at the Cleric and the Wizard and decided to attack the Cleric. The Warlock's intention was to edge the odds of one of us becoming the traitor. And since we didn't know at the time that the traitor would become a monster, he also wanted to weaken the traitor. However, he rolled 12 on his attack and the Cleric rolled 2. The 10 mental damage killed the Cleric.

When the Wizard turned traitor, we had to think for a moment how many cultists he should get. Either he gets 4 (there was a Fighter as well, 4 players total) or 3. We quickly picked 4 and moved on but wanted to see if we choose correctly. Our logic was that the Wizard was also dead, yet he should still count for the Adventurer total, so the dead Cleric should as well. Did we make the right call or should the traitor have only gotten 3 cultists?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but I think the attack by the Warlock was illegal. At page 10, the rulebook states "You can’t attack anyone until after the haunt
starts." And you should know who the traitor is the moment the haunt starts, no?

Comment: Normally yes, but this haunt starts without a known traitor. You go through one round of play without a traitor before one shows up. It's not even a hidden traitor situation, he just doesn't exist. But you are inside the haunt before there's a traitor. It's a unique haunt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the Haunt specifically says to not count dead adventurers, then you should always include them when calculating goals and other numbers.

And as long as the Haunt says number of *adventurers* and not number of *heroes*, then yes, the traitor would receive 4 cultists.

From [the rulebook](https://media.wizards.com/2017/avalon_hill/BaBG_Rulebook.pdf) (page 13 under **Playing the Haunt**):

> Certain haunts require something to be done a number of times equal to the number of adventurers or heroes. Unless the haunt states otherwise, that number includes any adventurers or heroes who have died during the haunt.